# Quantifying activity by the time of a day of the week

Tags: gui-design, charts, data-visualisation

First post here, but I'm really having trouble getting an idea of how to visualize a certain piece of data for a project.

Right now, we are trying to show a certain amount of activity on a given day and given time. Ideally, it'd be great to see it compared across an entire week.

I have created few examples below, but I feel like there is a better option. I'd appreciate any ideas or insight! I'm kind of having a hard time finding a direciton.

[image: screen-shot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like the grid option you generated, it is pretty clear to see the entire week at one time. For seeing the entire week, one other option you might consider is a piano chart or heatmap type chart.

Piano charts are table-style charts that make it easy to see differences in data-density. They visualize the data using a scale of brightness, size, color, transparency, or imagery. The more/higher values there are for a given point, the more intense, dark, opaque, etc. the corresponding fill.

[image: ZingChart piano chart gallery example]

This was made using ZingChart, a JavaScript charting library. It allows interactive tooltips over each tile.

In your case, tooltips would also be helpful. In addition, a color palette that gets less saturated along a single hue might work well. For example, http://www.herethere.net/~samson/php/color_gradient/?cbegin=163d6b&cend=e3ecf8&steps=10

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll the heat map solution out. Might be an interesting way of actually showing this type of data.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it would be even better if you explain exactly what makes this a good presentation format. Once you back up your suggestion, you'll have a +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Combine your lower chart with a top 10 lowest to highest, or vice versa, table to the right, and you're done! Seems to me the user does not need to see all data points, only the most significant ones.

Sidenote: personally I find heat map and time difficult to combine in one chart.

Cheers!